# Who was God seeking to kill in Exodus 4:24-26?

Tags: genesis, exodus

(KJV)Exodus 4:24-26

> And it came to pass by the way in the inn, that the Lord met him, and sought to kill him. [25] Then Zipporah took a sharp stone, and cut off the foreskin of her son, and cast it at his feet, and said, Surely a bloody husband art thou to me. [26] So he let him go: then she said, A bloody husband thou art , because of the circumcision.

(KJV)Genesis 17:14

> And the uncircumcised man child whose flesh of his foreskin is not circumcised, that soul shall be cut off from his people; he hath broken my covenant.

In Genesis God promises to cut off the soul of the uncircumcised from his people & in Exodus the same issue of circumcision comes to the fore but what is puzzling is that its not clear who God wanted to kill in Exodus.Could it be Moses because he had not circumcised his son or the son because his father had not circumcised him?

Comment: But my question is not a duplicate of that one because mine seeks to find out the identify of who God wanted to kill unlike the other one which already pointed to Moses as the victim.its not clear according to the text who God wanted to kill